# Quais os tamanhos padrões das imagens do android?

Tags: java, android, imagem

Estou criando meu primeiro aplicativo na plataforma Android e até onde eu sei um dos pontos negativos dessa plataforma é que os dispositivos existentes no mercado possuem diferentes tamanhos de telas.

Eu criei um projeto no Eclipse e verifiquei que ele cria 4 tipos de pastas para adicionar as imagens, e a minha dúvida é a seguinte: Como saber qual o tamanho das imagens referente a cada tipo de tela? Eu tenho uma imagem com o tamanho de 150x100 e funciona corretamente para a tela do S3, mas em outros celulares com telas menores fica bastante diferente. O que tenho que fazer para deixar todos de acordo, indiferente do tamanho da tela?

Qual o tamanho das imagens para cada pasta, se tenho uma imagem para S3 no tamanho 150x100?

Comment: Não é a plataforma Android (baseado em Linux) que possui vários tamanhos de tela, e sim os dispositivos que há utilizam. Normalmente são dispositivos móveis e portanto é comum para qualquer plataforma com _target_ para estes dispositivos terem esta característica (Windows Phone, PalmOS). Também não pode ser considerado um ponto negativo pois isto permite dispositivos variados, com diferentes custos e aplicações finais, atendendo uma gama maior de aplicações.

Comment: @DiegoCNascimento Acho que ele falou do ponto de vista do desenvolvedor, referindo-se à maior complexidade para construir o aplicativo devido à variedade de tamanhos de telas que ele vai precisar atender.

Comment: Exatamente @Piovezan

Comment: Eu tenho a mesma duvida. Eu não sei se cada pasta precisa ter uma imagem com uma resolução especifica. Se ela é defina em pixel ou dpi.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Não é que existam tamanhos padrão, afinal sua imagem pode ocupar um cantinho da tela ou até uma tela cheia. No entanto, existem recomendações.

A questão é: seu layout deve ser redimensionado de acordo com o tamanho da tela do usuário. Se você usar imagens muito grandes elas vão ficar estranhas e pesadas em telas pequenas. Se usar imagens pequenas elas vão ficar serrilhadas em telas grandes.

Na [documentação](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#DeclaringTabletLayouts) referente a isso, a solução mais recente apontada é utilizar faixas de tamanhos para largura, altura ou ambos. Isso é feito nomeando os diretórios com um padrão específico. Por exemplo:

- `sw600dp`: a pasta será usada em telas onde a altura e a largura são ambas maiores ou iguais a **600** pixels<sup>[1]</sup>.
- `w720dp`: a pasta será usada em telas onde a largura é maior ou igual a **720** pixels<sup>[1]</sup>.
- `h720dp`: a pasta será usada em telas onde a altura é maior e igual a **720** pixels<sup>[1]</sup>.

Você deve configurar seu aplicativo para informar ao Android quais as resoluções suportadas.

Somente para ilustração, você poderia criar pastas com larguras para **480**, **600** e **720** pixels<sup>[1]</sup> com uma imagem para exibir em tela cheia. As faixas onde seriam:

- Até **479**: o Android usa a pasta `res/layout/`
- De **480** até **599**: o Android usa a pasta `res/layout-w480dp`
- De **600** até **719**: o Android usa a pasta `res/layout-w600dp`
- A partir de **720**: o Android usa a pasta `res/layout-w720dp`

A imagens deveriam ter pelo menos o tamanho do limite superior das faixas. Por exemplo, como a primeira faixa vai até 479 pixels<sup>[1]</sup>, A imagem deve ter pelo menos 479 pixels<sup>[1]</sup> para não precisar ser ampliada e assim sofrer deformação.

*** *Nota [1]:*** embora eu tenha usado a unidade "pixel" no texto acima, foi apenas com o intuito de simplificar o texto. A unidade é *dp* (*density-independent pixels*).

Comment: Uma correção: em sw600dp por exemplo, dp significa density-independent pixels, o que é diferente de pixels (px). 600dp é um valor de densidade absoluta, enquanto que pixels indicam uma densidade relativa (a densidade absoluta correspondente vai depender do tamanho da tela em centímetros quadrados ou polegadas quadradas).

Comment: @Piovezan Corretíssimo, eu não queria complicar a postagem com uma unidade diferente e esqueci de colocar uma nota. Obrigado.

Answer (score 12):

Não vou dar uma explicação extensa aqui, somente ensinar a calcular os tamanhos de imagens para cada densidade, que é o objetivo da pergunta. Para uma explicação geral sobre densidade, resolução em pixels, etc. é recomendado consultar a [documentação](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

As densidades são, em ordem da menor para a maior: ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi e xxxhdpi.

Existe uma relação de proporção entre elas (1:2:3:4:6:8), que quer dizer: um figura mdpi é o dobro do tamanho de uma ldpi (relação 2:1), hdpi é o triplo de uma ldpi (relação 3:1), etc. Obviamente, ldpi tem o mesmo tamanho de ldpi, isto é, uma relação de 1:1.

Porém essa relação só tem utilidade do jeito que está (1:2:3:4:6:8) se você toma como base a densidade ldpi, que é a mais baixa. Se você tomar como base uma outra resolução, precisará recalcular esses valores (a proporção entre eles será mantida).

Por exemplo: tomando o caso do seu Samsung SIII, que tem densidade xhdpi. A relação de proporção para ele mesmo é 4:4 = 1. Portanto tome o valor 4 como divisor (segundo operando de uma divisão). O dividendo (primeiro operando) será a densidade para a qual você deseja calcular o tamanho da imagem. Por exemplo, se quer calcular para hdpi, a proporção será 3:4 = 0,75. Ou seja, a imagem hdpi correspondente será 0,75 vezes (ou três quartos) menor que a imagem xhdpi. Isso quer dizer que os 150x100 pixels em xhdpi vão se tornar 112,5 x 75 pixels (ou 112 x 75, já que tem que ser números inteiros) em uma tela hdpi.

A mesma lógica pode ser aplicada para obter as imagens nas demais densidades. Assim:

```
xxxhdpi = 300x200 px
xxhdpi = 225x150 px
mdpi = 75x50 px
ldpi = 37x25 px
```

Answer (score 1):

Para ajudar você no seu primeiro App e a criar as imagens para cada densidade automaticamente recomendo o uso da ferramenta .

[Android Asset Studio](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/index.html)