# Erro ao setar Background

Tags: android

Ao tentar alterar o background (imagem ou cor) ocorre o seguinte erro. O que pode ser?

[MEU XML[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYBPP.png)

[image: ACTIVITY]

```
07-22 20:29:52.223    4967-4967/? 
E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{priscilla.com.br.nossahistoria/priscilla.com.br.nossahistoria.SplashCreen}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class <unknown>
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
         Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class <unknown>
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
                at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:653)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:678)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
                at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:251)
                at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
                at priscilla.com.br.nossahistoria.SplashCreen.onCreate(SplashCreen.java:15)
                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
         Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:586)
                at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:653)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:678)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
                at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:251)
                at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
                at priscilla.com.br.nossahistoria.SplashCreen.onCreate(SplashCreen.java:15)
                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
         Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
                at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
                at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:483)
                at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:351)
                at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:773)
                at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1935)
                at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
                at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:2785)
                at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:385)
                at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:174)
                at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:170)
                at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:586)
                at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:653)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:678)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
                at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
                at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:251)
                at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
                at priscilla.com.br.nossahistoria.SplashCreen.onCreate(SplashCreen.java:15)
                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke
```

Comment: Por favor edite sua pergunta com o código que gera esse erro ou pelo menos um fragmento do mesmo

Comment: Poderia colocar o xml também? acredito q o erro esteja nele!

Comment: <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".SplashCreen"
    android:background="@drawable/splashcreen">




</LinearLayout>

Comment: package priscilla.com.br.nossahistoria;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;



public class SplashCreen extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_creen);
    }


}

Comment: @PriscillaAndradeMachado tem como colocar o XML junto a pergunta?

Comment: acabei de colocar @Dener

Comment: No nome da classe, você não queria dizer "SplashScreen"?

Comment: mas eu ja coloquei ... esse codigo é oq foi gerado qdo criamos o projeto

Comment: se eu tiro a imagem de background o programa roda normalmente, se eu não tiro aparece esse erro

Comment: Está dando `OutOfMemoryError`, meu primeiro palpite seria que a imagem é grande demais para o dispositivo (ou emulador) suportar. Qual o formato (extensão do arquivo) e o tamanho dela (largura e altura) em pixels, para dar uma noção? A(s) pasta(s) em que o drawable está (drawable-hdpi, drawable-xhdpi, etc.) e o modelo do dispositivo também podem ajudar.

Comment: A imagem esta em png e tem 78.1 kb ... 2126 x 3544 pixeis

Comment: Não sei muito de android, mas talvez seu erro esteja relacionado a esse: 
[SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20762720/android-view-inflateexception-binary-xml-file-line-1-error-inflating-class-andr).

Comment: Verefique a Thread que chama a splash

Comment: No mesmo diretorio que a pasta drawable crie uma pasta chamada drawable-nodpi e coloque a img dentro dessa pasta

Answer (score 0):

Tente usar uma imagem menor para o seu layout ou veja se sua aplicação não está consumindo muita memória do dispositivo, assim deixando pouco espaço para a renderização da imagem.

Comment: irei tentar ... obg pessoal

Answer (score 0):

A imagem é relativamente grande mesmo. Diferentes dispositivos possuem diferentes configurações de memória e uma imagem grande que seja suportada por um pode não ser suportada por outro. Redimensione a imagem original para tamanhos menores e coloque cada tamanho na pasta `res/drawable-` apropriada (`res/drawable-mdpi`, `res/drawable-hdpi`, `res/drawable-xhdpi`, etc.), assim cada dispositivo irá carregar uma figura do tamanho apropriado para sua capacidade. [Esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/492/quais-os-tamanhos-padr%C3%B5es-das-imagens-do-android) pode ajudar a calcular os tamanhos apropriados.